# checking if arraylist is sorted or not

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to check if the elements in the arraylist are arranged in ascending order or not. and when i use this code, the output shows "not sorted" even for a sorted array. why is it showing the wrong output?**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array1.add(i, sc.nextInt());
        array2.add(i, array1.get(i));
    }

    Collections.sort(array1);
    if (array1 == array2) {
        System.out.println("sorted");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("not sorted");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `==` operator tests that two references both point to the same object. It doesn't test whether two objects are equal. You can compare two lists are equal with the `List.equals()` method -- e.g., `if ( array1.equals( array2 ))`.

Comment: Sorting can take O(n log n) or more. You could instead just test for sorted order in O(n).

Answer (score 2):

"==" checks weather two object identical that means it check weather they point to the same memory location. If your array1 is on @698 location your array2 will be somewhere else like @700 ,so they don't point to the same location that's why it shows they are not equal. You better check it on this way:

```
    if (array1.equals(array2)){
        System.out.println("They are equal");
    } else{
        System.out.println("They are not equal");
```

Then it shows the right answer

Answer (score 2):

The error using `==` instead of `equals` is clear. For arrays there is `Arrays.equals(int[] lhs, int[] rhs)`.

However `sort` does too much work, and needs a copy of the array.
Better:

```
static boolean isSorted(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i - 1)) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Could even be more general:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isSorted(List<T> list) {
```

Comment: Do the int array names in **Arrays.equals(int[] lhs, int[] rhs)** mean left-hand side and right-hand side? I am unfamiliar with the **Arrays.equals()** method. Thank you pre-emptively for clarification.

Comment: @KemperLee My ad-hoc naming, yes, left-hand side. Arrays, Collections, Files all are nice utility classes.